# How to identify source and load in AC network?

Tags: electrical

If I have a AC network with two black box components connected with each other and I can tap into all voltage and current measurements, how do I determine which component is the source and which is the load.?

In case of DC, I can identify this by looking at the direction of current. In AC, current is alternating, so the information I can obtain is if the network is lagging or leading. Not able to say which block is source or load.

Comment: If these are two port boxes and one port from each is joined. I would look at the other ends and try to inject a signal if possible AC coupled and look for a response

Answer (score -1):

Hi: I guess it is really up to you,  you could decide what to call them arbitrarily.

Or, you could compute the average power flow into each box.  If the power in is positive, the box is absorbing power, you could call that the load.  If the power in is negative, the box is supplying power. You could call that the source.  All physically existing circuits should obey conservation of energy, so the sum of the two average powers must be zero.

Comment: Shoud i use power meters to compute the sign of average power flow?

Comment: You are missing an massive part of the explanation, the sign of the power doesn't mean anything if you don't mention the measurement convention used.

Comment: The convention in circuit theory is that current flows INTO the POSITIVE terminal of a device. Thus, current*voltage is the instantaneous power flowing INTO the device.   To find the average power, average the instantaneous power over time.  (For repetitive signals, over one period is good)

Comment: @user69795 If you connect amp meter in the load convention. However if i connect the amp meter in a generator convention, the current will have a Negative sign on the measurement equipment. here the problem is literally just an analysis of sign on a multi meter, there is no need to compute the power.

Comment: @user69795 I will remove my down vote if you update your answer with proper schematic of the measurements. Your explanation is correct for someone who already understand the concept of power flow. However, your question is not clear for some one like OP who need a basic explanation of power flow in AC.

Comment: For AC circuits, one can use complex numbers to represent voltages and currents.  When using this technique, the average power over a period can be computed as Power=Re( voltage* conj(current)).  For a box with terminals, compute the power into each of the terminals and add them up.  If the power is positive, the box is absorbing power.  If the power is negative, the box is supplying power.  I guess you could call a box and supplies power a "source" and one that absorbs power a "load".